# Searching for duplicates without any collection or sorting

Tags: java, array

I have written code which is easy to understand, but may not be efficient but will solve the purpose.

```
public static void main(String a[]){
        int ar[] ={1,2,3,4};
        boolean flag=false;
        int count=0;
        while(count<ar.length){
            for(int i=0;i<ar.length-1;i++){
                if(ar[count]==ar[i+1] && count !=i+1){
                    flag=true;
                }
        }
            count++;
        }
        if(flag){

        System.out.println("Duplicate Exists in Array!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Duplicates Doesn't Exists in Array!");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

As you may be aware, your solution takes O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time.  Sorting can bring that down to O(*n* log *n*).  Hashing can produce an O(*n*) solution.  Of course, for a four-element array, performance isn't an issue at all.

---

Please take care to indent your code consistently.

---

This kind of loop structure…

```
int count = 0;
while (count < ar.length) {
    …
    count++;
}
```

… is more easily recognizable when written as a for-loop:

```
for (int count = 0; count < ar.length; count++) {
    …
}
```

Once you do that, you'll see nested for-loop, which is easier to understand:

```
for (int count = 0; count < ar.length; count++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length - 1; i++) {
        if (ar[count] == ar[i + 1] && cont != i + 1) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But you are inspecting almost every pair of elements twice.  Typically, the inner loop limits are written to avoid half the work:

```
for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (ar[i] == ar[j]) {
            // Duplicate found!
            …
        }
    }
}
```

---

Variables named `flag` (or that act as a flag) are usually a bad idea, because they express your intentions indirectly.  In the case of duplicate element detection, once you've found a single duplicate, you're all done.  There should be a `break`, or better yet, a `return`:

```
public static boolean duplicateExists(int[] ar) {
    for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (ar[i] == ar[j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ar = …;
    System.out.println(duplicateExists(ar) ? "Duplicate exists in array!"
                                           : "No duplicates in array!");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> I have written code which is easy to understand

According to whom?

If *you* think it's easy to understand, it's probably because you're the one who have written it. It's easy to understand your own code when you just wrote it.

Now, I have to admit that the code is quite understandable, yes. There are however some things you can change to improve the understandability. Some things have been covered by 200_success already, but there's one more important one: **Naming**.

---

```
int ar[]
```

It's easy to assume that `ar` is short for `array`, but that itself doesn't tell us much. `input` would be a better name.

---

```
boolean flag
```

200_success is correct about extracting a method and returning directly. Note the name of the method: `duplicateExists`. If you would use the `flag` variable (which you really shouldn't, please follow the advice of 200_success), a better name would be `duplicateFound`.

---

```
int count
```

A variable named `count` sounds like it's supposed to count the number of items in the entire array. That's not what your variable is doing. A common name for simple iterator variables is `i` (and then `j` for an inner loop). As long as you're not dealing with two-dimensional arrays, using the names `i` and `j` is OK. If you want to elaborate more on the names, you could name them something like `firstIndex` and `compareIndex`.

---

```
String a[]
```

Even though it's not used, the parameter to a main method is better named as `args`. Also please write it as `String[] a` to be consistent and to adhere to the convention of where to put those `[]`.

---

Spacing. Doyoulikereadingthingswithoutaspace? No? Thought so.

Look at this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<ar.length-1;i++){
    if(ar[count]==ar[i+1] && count !=i+1){
```

Please add more spaces. Operators, parenthesis and semicolons should have a space around them (some should have two - one before and one after).

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length - 1; i++) {
    if (ar[count] == ar[i+1] && count != i + 1) {
```